# Where should this cross-posted question live?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, cross-posting

The question *Mono Project: How to install Mono framework on Red Hat Linux which is compiled on centOS?*  was cross-posted to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/120165), [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/117286), and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398373).

Where should it end up living?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say Server Fault, but since it's such an entry-level, basic question I think it is a better fit for SU.

I moved the SO version (which is the only one that got answered) to SU, and deleted the other cross-site dupes.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really a programming question, and really doesn't have anything to do with server administration.  It is about computer software, so I would probably say Super User.

Comment: It's an OS question, similar to say "How do I put drivers for my printer on my Linux computer."

Answer (score 0):

It's about how to compile Mono for work servers. Should be on Server Fault.

Comment: Depending on usage, it could go either way.  Definitely not SO, and dummy points for the cross-posting.

Comment: The question stated that the target machine is a server, but the answer would be the same regardless whether it's server or desktop deployment - Mono is the same beast on either.